# Printing to CUPS from Windows

Tags: fedora, windows, cups, printer

Am running Fedora 23 on a desktop connected to HP Deskjet F2400 and I want to print to it from a Windows 10 laptop.

I have cups installed, but I have a few problems:

- I don't know the username and password, and after I used my desktop login account, it says forbidden access.
- Deskjet-F2400-series (Idle, Accepting Jobs, Not Shared, Server Default) Don't know if this is OK.
- I am unable to find this printer on the Dell laptop using `http://DELL-PC:631/printers/<printer>`

Comment: The username and password will be for the `root` account, unless CUPS has been configured differently.  In the CUPS admin web page click the Administrator tab (top of page) and on the right, under Server, you should see **Share printers connected to this system**.  Check this and click on **Change Settings**.

Comment: @garethTheRed but what should I do in windows? I tried to go to add a new printer, after that?

Comment: WIndows? That's not a Linux distro ;-)  Maybe a question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: @garethTheRed thanks a lot for your help. the windows is my father's